# Using global variable with application context in flask

Tags: flask

I defined a customized logger in **mylogger.py**, and the log dir is defined is **config.py** as LOG_DIR='/var/log'. In mylogger.py, the logger does some init work with LOG_DIR.

```
//mylogger.py
from flask import current_app
log_path = os.path.join(current_app.config['LOG_DIR'],"all.log") 
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename = logPath)
....

//config.py
LOG_DIR = "/var/log"
```

Flask says an error message:

```
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with modules.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

How could I use variable in **config.py** within app_context? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def register_logging(app):
    log_path = os.path.join(app.config['LOG_DIR'],"all.log") 
    handler = logging.FileHandler(filename = logPath)

def create_app():
    app = Flask()
    register_logging(app)
    return app

app = create_app()
```

or just import config.py

```
from config import LOG_DIR
```